# Instance initialization in Python Unit tests error

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am somewhat new with Python and I'm stuck on an error I can't seem to find here or anywhere else on the internet. Might be a simple one though:

I have a unit test class with witch I want to test methods of my 'controller' class. The unit test class looks like this:

```
import unittest
from Controller import Controller

class ControllerUnitTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_no_ants_must_be_in_own_dead_ants_list(self):
        controller = Controller()
        self.assertTrue(controller.__ourBots[0] is None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

I am simply checking whether an attribute in the controller class (ourBots, a list) has no items in it.

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================
ERROR:   test_no_ants_must_be_in_own_dead_ants_list
(ControllerUnitTests.ControllerUnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rgroenve\Python\KamikazeMieren\src\ControllerUnitTests.py", line 22, in   test_no_ants_must_be_in_own_dead_ants_list
self.assertTrue(controller.__ourBots[0] is None)
AttributeError: Controller instance has no attribute '_ControllerUnitTests__ourBots'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

It looks like it is searching for an attribute within its own class, instead of my controller class. I don't understand why and how though.

The top of the controller class looks like this:

```
class Controller:

__priority = 0
__ourBots = []

def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Does the `Controller()` have `ourBots`?

Comment: Yes it does, however, it is declared as a 'private' variable like this: __ourBots = []

I understood that in Python there aren't really any private variables, and so I can reach them from within my unit test.

Comment: Thanks for your help already, I added the top part of the controller to my question

Comment: Don't use double leading underscores unless you *really* need to. FYI, you never *really* need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members with two leading underscores are "private" variables in Python, ie. they use name magingling to be less easily accessible from the outside: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

You'll have to either change the name of the member in the unit test to the mangled one (which is very ugly) or, preferrably, use some non-"private" interface of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I never thought I had to search for the solution right there! Thank you so much!!